# Understanding dereference operator and pointers in C, and logic of a small program

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

I got this code snippet from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/71119/printing-the-contents-of-a-string-array-using-pointers?newreg=039e39b36371439ebc48f06e2437009e#answer-71121):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        char *pos = argv[i];
        while (*pos != '\0') {
            printf("%c\n", *(pos++));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Why are we starting the iterations of `for` loop at `i=1`, why not
   start it at `i=0`, especially when we are ending the iterations at
   `i<argc` and Not at `i<=argc`?
2. The second, third and fourth last lines of code! In `char *pos =
   argv[i];`, we declare a pointer type variable and assign it a
   pointer to a commandline parameter passed when running the program.

   Then in `while (*pos != '\0')`, `*pos` *dereferences* the pointer
   stored in `pos`, so `*pos` contains the actual value pointed by the
   pointer stored in `pos`.

   Then in `printf("%c\n", *(pos++));`, we have **`*(pos++)`**, and
   that is the actual question:  (a) Why did he *increment* `pos`, and
   (b) what is the meaning of dereferencing `(pos++)` with the
   dereference operator `*`?

Comment: Have you executed the code and observed the output?

Comment: look up "null-terminated strings"

Comment: Run the code in a debugger and you'll be able to see why the code ignores argv[0] and what is happening in the rest of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Why are we starting the iterations of for loop at i=1, why not start it at i=0, especially when we are ending the iterations at
>      i

We start at 1 because `argv[0]` holds the name of the program itself which we don't care about. Ignoring the first element of an array does not move the index of the last array.
We have `argc` elements stored in `argv[]`. Therefore we mustn't run until `i==argc` but need to stop one element earlier, just as with every other array.

> 2. The second, third and fourth last lines of code! In char *pos = argv[i];, we declare a pointer type variable and assign it a pointer
>      to a commandline parameter passed when running the program.

Correct. `pos` is a pointer and points to the first string passed via command line.

> Then in while (*pos != '\0'), *pos dereferences the pointer stored in
>   pos, so *pos contains the actual value pointed by the pointer stored
>   in pos.

`*pos` contains the first character of the string we are currently inspecting.

> Then in printf("%c\n", *(pos++));, we have *(pos++), and that is the
>   actual question: (a) Why did he increment pos, and (b) what is the
>   meaning of dereferencing (pos++) with the dereference operator *?

You have 2 things here:
1. `(pos++)`: `pos` is a pointer to `char` and with `++` increment the pointer to point to the next element, i.e. to the next `char` after taking its value.
2. The value of `pos` (before the post-increment) is taken and dereferenced to read the `char` at that position.

As a result the `while` loop will read all characters, while the `for` loop handles all strings.

Comment: if `pos` contains the pointer to the _entire_ string, and not the pointer to just the first character of the string, why does `*pos` contain _ONLY_ the first character of the string, and not the _entire string_ ?

Comment: What exactly do you think, a "string" is in C? A string is just a bunch of `char` with a terminating `\0` at the end. Therefore pointing to a string means pointing to the first `char`.

Comment: @Sie `pos` does actually point to only the first character of the string. Then `pos++` changes it to point to the second character of the string, which works because the characters of the string are contiguous in memory.

Answer (score 2):

**For the first part,**

> *Why are we starting the iterations of for loop at `i=1`, why not start it at `i=0`, especially when we are ending the iterations at `i<argc` and Not at `i<=argc`?*

Because, for hosted environment, `argv[0]` represents the executable name. Here, we're only interested in supplied command line arguments other than the executable name itself.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §5.1.2.2.1

> > If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the string pointed to by `argv[0]`
> >     represents the *program name;* [....] If the value of `argc` is
> >     greater than one, the strings pointed to by `argv[1]` through `argv[argc-1]`
> >     represent the program parameters.

*Point to note:* using `i<=argc` as the loop condition would be wrong, as C arrays use 0-based indexing.

**For the second part,**

> *(a) Why did he increment `pos`, and (b) what is the meaning of dereferencing `(pos++)` with the dereference operator `*`?*

`*(pos++),` can also be read as `*pos; pos++;` which, reads the current value from the memory location pointed to by `pos` and then advances `pos` by one element.

To elaborate, at the beginning of each iteration of the `for` loop, by saying

```
char *pos = argv[i];
```

`pos` holds the pointer to the starting of the *string* which holds the supplied program parameter and by continuous increment (upto `NULL`), we're basically traversing the *string* and by dereferencing, we're reading the value at those locations.

---

Just for the sake of completeness, let me state, that the whole `for` loop body

```
    char *pos = argv[i];
    while (*pos != '\0') {
        printf("%c\n", *(pos++));
```

can be substituted using

```
    puts(argv[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why are we starting the iterations of for loop at i=1, why not start
>   it at i=0, especially when we are ending the iterations at i

Because first parameter is name of the program - and it seems author is not interested in it.

Second case is basically similar to the following (`argv[i]` basically being a `char *`):

So you have something like this:

```
char * c = "Hello"
```

and then `char * p = c;`

Now you have

```
+------------------+
| H e l l o /0     |
| ^                |
| |                |
+------------------+
  |
  |
  +
  p
```

When you do `p++` you have

```
+------------------+
| H e l l o /0     |
|   ^              |
|   |              |
+------------------+
    |
  +-+
  +
  p
```

If you do now `*p` - the value you get is 'e'.

`*(p++)` is basically same as above two steps, just due to post increment, first the value where `p` points will be retrieved (before increment), and then `p` will advance.

> Then in printf("%c\n", *(pos++));, we have *(pos++), and that is the
>   actual question: (a) Why did he increment pos, and (b) what is the
>   meaning of dereferencing (pos++) with the dereference operator *?

So in the `while` loop the author is traversing through the whole string until he meets null terminator '\0' and printing each character.

This on the other hand is repeated for each parameter in `argv` using the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

> Why are we starting the iterations of for loop at i=1, why not start
> it at i=0, especially when we are ending the iterations at i < argc and
> Not at i <= argc?

Note that the `argc` contains the name of the program being executed too which will be the first (given the number zero) thing to be counted. So the actual arguments starts from 1 and ends at `total - 1`

---

A note here, the command line arguments are stored in array of pointer to char, ie

```
argv[0] -> "YourFirstArguement"
argv[1] -> "YourSecondArguement"
.
.
argv[argc-1] -> "YourLastArguement" //Remember argc-1 is the last argument
```

and so. Note that each of the argument is a null terminated string

---

So in

```
char *pos = argv[i]; // Create another pointer to each string
while (*pos != '\0') {
  printf("%c\n", *(pos++)); // Note %c, you're printing char by char.
}
```

You're just printing character by character using the format specifier `%c` in printf. So you need to dereference character by character in the while loop and this answers

> a) Why did he increment pos, and
>
> b) what is the meaning of dereferencing (pos++) with the dereference operator *?

Comment: Your first code block is confusing, since that isn't legal code.. maybe omitting the `char *` would be better